# How to check if a restart of open-iscsi was ok

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, scripts

I am working on a bash script to connect a iscsi initiator to a target. After I have edited the iscsid.conf in the initiator I have to restart the open-iscsi with the command:

```
service open-iscsi restart
```

Is it a possible way to check if the restart was ok, if it was it will try to connect to target with:

```
iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p 10.05.02.10
```

Comment: You can check the status of the above service by running `sudo service open-iscsi status`.If there is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grep for the process, if it is running it will display otherwise it won't show

command:  `$ ps -ef | grep iscsi`